# What is Penny's full name before marriage?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory

In the Big Bang Theory, one of the main characters is "Penny". In the 12 seasons, does it get mentioned what's Penny's full name before she married to Leonard Hofstadter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She didn't have one.

It is never mentioned before she became Hofstadter.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(The_Big_Bang_Theory))…

> Penny is the only main character of the program whose last name was not revealed, although she has been occasionally referred to or addressed with the last name Hofstadter since her wedding.

Comment: She obviously **had** one, only we didn't know it.. Could be Wyatt though..

Comment: @Vishwa Wasn't Wyatt Penny's father's first name?

Comment: @Sandun Wyatt is used in as both First name and Family name. The reason I mentioned **Could be**..

Comment: Wyatt is definitely his first name. The surname is Teller. I have [added my answer to the original question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/115694/65183).